# Trying to get options closing data over 1 month period using Yahoo Finance queries

Tags: python, finance, yahoo-finance, yahoo

I am trying to use the yahoo finance queries to get daily data (particularly closing value) for option contracts.

```
https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v8/finance/chart/CYH220121C00001000?symbol=CYH220121C00001000&period1=1624424708&period2=1627002308&useYfid=true&interval=5m&includePrePost=false&lang=en-US&region=US
```

Currently I get this as a response.

```
{"chart":{"result":[{"meta":{"currency":"USD","symbol":"CYH220121C00001000","exchangeName":"OPR","instrumentType":"OPTION","firstTradeDate":1600660800,"regularMarketTime":1614966165,"gmtoffset":-14400,"timezone":"EDT","exchangeTimezoneName":"America/New_York","regularMarketPrice":7.7,"chartPreviousClose":7.7,"previousClose":7.7,"scale":3,"priceHint":2,"currentTradingPeriod":{"pre":{"timezone":"EDT","end":1628049600,"start":1628049600,"gmtoffset":-14400},"regular":{"timezone":"EDT","end":1628135940,"start":1628049600,"gmtoffset":-14400},"post":{"timezone":"EDT","end":1628135940,"start":1628135940,"gmtoffset":-14400}},"dataGranularity":"5m","range":"","validRanges":["1d","5d","1mo","3mo","6mo","1y","ytd","max"]},"indicators":{"quote":[{}]}}],"error":null}}
```

I am not sure if this is correct or if I need to change my request. I am trying to get 30-31 different points for each property, but currently just getting one.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: did you try modules like `yfinance` ? Do you have link to API documentation for this function?

Comment: No I have not. I dont have the API documentation. Does yfinance have requests that look like the one I sent?

Answer (score 1):

yfinance has a very easy way to get the option chain, which you can use to get the historical data from. In your case you would use `yf.Ticker('CYH220121C00001000').history('max')` to get all available data, works for most standard contracts.